# ADB over USB: port-forwarding <150kB/s despite Internet & USB > 2MB/s

Tags: android, usb, adb, portforwarding

Working with ADB over USB, I've noticed that port-forwarding is very slow (~150kB/s), despite the fact that my:

- internet connection is fast (~2MB/s), *and*
- USB connection is fast (~5MB/s)

I'm looking for help debugging.

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to investigate the cause -- or of course, ideas about how to fix!

---

#### Details:

Running ADB over USB, I can download-then-pull a file very quickly, which shows that my internet connection and USB connection are "fast" (>1MB/s). For example, I can grab a 100MB file in 90sec:

```
$ cat getfile.sh
R=tempdl
adb shell "curl -k $1 > /sdcard/$R"
adb pull /sdcard/$R
adb shell rm /sdcard/$R   

$ ./getfile.sh https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
```

**That completes in 90sec.**

But if I try using adb port forwarding, like:

`adb forward tcp:8000 tcp:8000`

... in conjunction with a port-forwarding app on Android (take your pick) to grab the same file, then I never see speeds above **120kB/sec.**

I'd appreciate any insight into why the port-forwarding might be so slow, when my internet connection is fast, and my USB connection is fast. And of course any ideas about how to mitigate.